# Getting CPU, load, memory data from Nagios API

Tags: api, nagios

I am using Nagios to monitor our servers. It comes with a restful API. I can see a tab 'metrics' in the admin dashboard, I cannot figure out in their documentation if it's possible to query for this metric data through the API.

Comment: Are you using Nagios XI?

Comment: Yes I am, the API is up and working. I just want some kind of direction on how to get this data from the API.

Comment: What data are you specifically looking for?

Comment: Under the "Details" tab there is a "Metrics" link. The page displays "disk usage, load usage, cpu usage, memory usage"

Comment: With the API, we can get the data used to build the metrics, but not in form of the metrics component itself - does this make sense? I'll post an answer here shortly - and hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no metrics export in the API. But we can get the RRD data, or the current perfdata.

Let's use host: localhost, service: Current Load as an example. Lets say we wanted the current perfdata, the API URL would look like this:

`http://nagiosxi/nagiosxi/api/v1/objects/servicestatus?apikey=YOURAPIKEY&pretty=1&host_name=localhost&service_description=Current+Load`

Then, the line "performance_data" is the one we want:

`"performance_data": "load1=0.120;5.000;10.000;0; load5=0.200;4.000;6.000;0; load15=0.130;3.000;4.000;0;",`

Or, alternatively, you can use the RRD export portion of the API with the following url:

`http://nagiosxi/nagiosxi/api/v1/objects/rrdexport?apikey=YOURAPIKEY&pretty=1&host_name=localhost&service_description=Current+Load`

Both of these pieces of data are essentially is what is used to calculate via the Metrics component.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This helps but it's still unclear what load1, load5 and load15 is?

Comment: Those are the standard values relating to your CPU load. 1 min avg, 5 min avg, 15 min avg.

Comment: Also, in Nagios XI, there is a help menu that fully details the API. If you click 'Help' in the top navigation, and then 'Objects Reference' in the left hand navigation, it should be able to help further.

Comment: So just to clarify, in your robust monitoring platform, there is no way to query memory usage, disk usage, swap etc? We would have to write a custom plugin to do this ?

Comment: You're asking for data that exists in a component to be queried from the API? The metrics component data that is displayed is NOT the plugin data that is returned to Nagios - you understand that, right? So why would the API return it? You can get any plugin data you want from the API - using a very similar call as to above. The full *REFERENCE OF API COMMANDS* is available to you in your XI installation.